# Writing asm at Marshal.AllocCoTaskMem causing AccessViolation Exception?

Tags: c#, assembly, access-violation

I have injected inside another application and I have this "user call" function I want to call.  So I've written a simple ASM wrapper that just aligns up my params on the right registers and calls the function.

This is  my code for placing my ASM bytes into the application.

```
ASMWrapper = Marshal.AllocCoTaskMem(asm.Length);
Marshal.Copy(asm, 0, ASMWrapper, asm.Length);
```

After this I just register a delagate at this location and I'm good to go. Now the funny thing is that this works on 4 out of my 5 tested computers, and the last one I've tried to format and install with a clean Windows 7 Ultimate. Just like the other computers. It still doesn't work.

What I can do though, is using `WriteProcessMemory` to just write my ASM code. If I do this it works, since then I can place the code where the original code is.

Is there anyone who knows why it behaves like this? I would prefer using the `AllocCoTaskMem` way to place my asm instead of trying to find somewhere to place it manually.

Comment: It sounds like your asm code is sensitive to where it resides. What does it look like?

Comment: It's probably not the asm code because the crash occurs at the first instruction which is "push ebp //0x55". The strangest thing is that it works on my other computers with the same windows 7 ultimate installed. The only difference I think is the hardware. I hope this helps.

Comment: What's the crash - A/V or something else?

Comment: The crash is a "System.AccessViolationException was unhandled
Message: Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt." But this only occurs when the memory is allocated by AllocCoTaskMem or AllocHGlobal. When I enter the asm manually it doesn't crash, at for example 0x00B1C032. Which is a value that is much lower than the address returned by the 2 given functions.

Comment: Are the other 4 machines identical to the 5th (problematic) one, or are they different OS versions or 32 vs. 64 bit etc.?

Comment: Is the memory that AllocCoTaskMem uses marked executable? I'd use VirtualAlloc for this and not take that chance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Nothing short of `VirtualAlloc` or `VirtualProtect` can give you a memory block that's both writable and executable. Use

```
VirtualAlloc(0, Size, MEM_RESERVE|MEM_COMMIT, PAGE_EXECUTE_READWRITE);
```

Neither of the allocators that you use allows execution of the memory they allocate.

The crash is contingent upon the system and BIOS settings for data execution prevention (DEP), and whether the CPU supports it. But pervasive DEP is where the industry is going, might as well play nice with it.

Comment: Thank you so much! This solved all my issues, I really appreciate it!